# What is the value of the PL segment if QL = 12?

Tags: geometry

For reference:
[image]

My progress...
the idea would be to demonstrate that $triangle AQL \cong \triangle LQC$

$\triangle PAB \sim QCB (AA)\\
\measuredangle PBA = \measuredangle QCB=90-\theta$

[image]

Could I say that $\triangle ABC$ is isoscelels without showing that BL is perpendicular to AC?

with the answer , the drawing to scale would look like this...

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, ABC isn't necessary isosceles in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D, H$ and $E$ are the midpoints of $\triangle ABC$, $\angle FDB=
\angle BEG$ and since $BDHE$ is a parallelogram, $DH =BE=EG, DB = EH=FD$  and $\angle BDH =\angle BEH$ , and $\angle FDH=\angle GEH$
so $\triangle FDH$ and $ \triangle GEH$ are congruent and $FH=GH$[image]

Comment: Beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. Please note your mistake is in trying to prove that $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles. $PL = QL$ holds regardless of whether $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles or not.

All we are given is that $\angle BAP = \angle BCQ = \theta$, and $BP$ and $BQ$ are perpendicular drawn to $AP$ and $CQ$ respectively. $L$ is the midpoint of $AC$.

We draw perp $BH$ from $B$ to $AC$. $LH = x$, $AL = LC = d$ (say).

[image]

As $\triangle BAP \sim \triangle BCQ$, $ \frac{BP}{BQ} = \frac{AP}{CQ} = \frac{AB}{BC} = k \ $ (say)

As quadrilateral $AHBP$ and $CHBQ$ are cyclic, we can apply Ptolemy's theorem.

In $AHBP$, $ \ AH \cdot BP + BH \cdot AP = AB \cdot HP$
$(d + x) \cdot k \cdot BQ + BH \cdot k \cdot CQ = k \cdot BC \cdot HP$

$(d + x) \cdot BQ + BH \cdot CQ = BC \cdot HP \tag1$

In $CHBQ$, $ \ CH \cdot BQ + BH \cdot CQ = BC \cdot HQ$

$(d - x) \cdot BQ + BH \cdot CQ = BC \cdot HQ \tag2$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$,
$2x \cdot BQ = BC \cdot (HP - HQ)$

$2x \sin \theta = HP - HQ \tag3$

Now $\angle BHP = \angle BAP = \theta$, so $\angle AHP = 90^\circ - \theta$. Similarly, $\angle BHQ = \angle BCQ = \theta$ and $\angle AHQ = 90^\circ - \theta$.

By law of cosine in $\triangle PHL$,
$PL^2 = x^2 + HP^2 - 2 x \cdot HP \cos(90^\circ - \theta)$
$PL^2 = x^2 + HP^2 - HP (HP - HQ) = x^2 + HP \cdot HQ\ $ (using $3$)

By law of cosine in $\triangle QHL$,
$QL^2 = x^2 + HQ^2 - 2 x \cdot HQ \cos(90^\circ + \theta)$
$QL^2 = x^2 + HQ^2 + HQ (HP - HQ) = x^2 + HP \cdot HQ\ $

So, $PL = QL = 12$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In figure we have:

$\angle DAE=\angle DCE$

$\Rightarrow \angle DCG=\angle EAF$

so right angled triangle ADC and AEC are similar, and we have:

$\angle DCA=\angle EAC$

hence triangles ADC and AEC are symmetric about BL, that is BL is perpendicular n AC. In this way PL and QL are also symmetric about BL , so they are equal and $PL=QL=12$.

Comment: I made the drawing to scale but it's different from yours...I can't find point B and E. Could you look at the statement, I posted with your observations

Comment: @petaarantes, B is not necessarily on the circle(but it can be). If B is as in my figure you will get points D and E.

Comment: $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle AEC$ are not similar unless you are assuming $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles.